# Override the dependencies added during running a project as an Eclipse Application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-pde

I am trying to write a custom launch configuration while running a plugin project as an eclipse application. I have to run the plugin with limited dependencies. Is it possible to override methods in `org.eclipse.pde.launching.EclipseApplicationLaunchConfiguration` ? If yes then how do I do it ?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you mean by 'limited dependencies'. Eclipse/OSGi will simply not run code if all the dependencies cannot be resolved.

Comment: By default when you open the plugins tab in the run configurations, the configuration will be set to run all the plugins in the work space. I am trying to add the required plugin and its dependencies without any manual work so that the eclipse work space opens only with the plugin I run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a custom configuration file

1. Extend the class `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchShortcut`
2. Override the method `createLaunchConfiguration`
3. Invoking `super.createLaunchConfiguration(element)` will return a `ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy`
4. Use the copy and set your own attributes that have to be modified
5. Attributes can be found in `IPDELauncherConstants`

Eclipse by default runs all the projects found in the workspace. This behavior can be modified by using the configuration created and overriding it with custom configuration.

```
public class LaunchShortcut extends JUnitLaunchShortcut {

class PluginModelNameBuffer {

    private List<String> nameList;

    PluginModelNameBuffer() {
        super();
        this.nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void add(final IPluginModelBase model) {
        this.nameList.add(getPluginName(model));
    }

    private String getPluginName(final IPluginModelBase model) {
        IPluginBase base = model.getPluginBase();
        String id = base.getId();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(id);

        ModelEntry entry = PluginRegistry.findEntry(id);
        if ((entry != null) && (entry.getActiveModels().length > 1)) {
            buffer.append('*');
            buffer.append(model.getPluginBase().getVersion());
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Collections.sort(this.nameList);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (String name : this.nameList) {
            if (result.length() > 0) {
                result.append(',');
            }
            result.append(name);
        }

        if (result.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}

@Override
protected ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy createLaunchConfiguration(final IJavaElement element)
        throws CoreException {
    ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy configuration = super.createLaunchConfiguration(element);
    configuration.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_VM_ARGUMENTS, "memory");
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.USE_PRODUCT, false);
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.USE_DEFAULT, false);
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.AUTOMATIC_ADD, false);
    addDependencies(configuration);

    return configuration;
}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
private void addDependencies(final ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy configuration) throws CoreException {
    PluginModelNameBuffer wBuffer = new PluginModelNameBuffer();
    PluginModelNameBuffer tBuffer = new PluginModelNameBuffer();
    Set<IPluginModelBase> addedModels = new HashSet<>();

    String projectName = configuration.getAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_PROJECT_NAME, "");
    IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(projectName);
    IPluginModelBase model = PluginRegistry.findModel(project);
    wBuffer.add(model);
    addedModels.add(model);

    IPluginModelBase[] externalModels = PluginRegistry.getExternalModels();
    for (IPluginModelBase externalModel : externalModels) {
        String id = externalModel.getPluginBase().getId();
        if (id != null) {
            switch (id) {
            case "org.eclipse.ui.ide.application":
            case "org.eclipse.equinox.ds":
            case "org.eclipse.equinox.event":
                tBuffer.add(externalModel);
                addedModels.add(externalModel);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    TreeSet<String> checkedWorkspace = new TreeSet<>();
    IPluginModelBase[] workspaceModels = PluginRegistry.getWorkspaceModels();
    for (IPluginModelBase workspaceModel : workspaceModels) {
        checkedWorkspace.add(workspaceModel.getPluginBase().getId());
    }

    EclipsePluginValidationOperation eclipsePluginValidationOperation = new EclipsePluginValidationOperation(
            configuration);
    eclipsePluginValidationOperation.run(null);

    while (eclipsePluginValidationOperation.hasErrors()) {
        Set<String> additionalIds = DependencyManager.getDependencies(addedModels.toArray(), true, null);
        if (additionalIds.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        additionalIds.stream().map(PluginRegistry::findEntry).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(ModelEntry::getModel)
                .forEach(addedModels::add);

        for (String id : additionalIds) {
            IPluginModelBase plugin = findPlugin(id);
            if (checkedWorkspace.contains(plugin.getPluginBase().getId())
                    && (!plugin.getPluginBase().getId().endsWith("tests"))) {
                wBuffer.add(plugin);
            } else {
                tBuffer.add(plugin);
            }
        }
        eclipsePluginValidationOperation.run(null);
    }
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.SELECTED_WORKSPACE_PLUGINS, wBuffer.toString());
    configuration.setAttribute(IPDELauncherConstants.SELECTED_TARGET_PLUGINS, tBuffer.toString());
}

protected IPluginModelBase findPlugin(final String id) {
    ModelEntry entry = PluginRegistry.findEntry(id);
    if (entry != null) {
        return entry.getModel();
     }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily override the methods in `EclipseApplicationLaunchConfiguration`. That would require writing a new launch configuration - probably by using the `org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes` extension point to define a new launch type.

`EclipseApplicationLaunchConfiguration` always uses the settings from the current entry in the 'Eclipse Application' section of the 'Run Configurations'. You can always edit the run configuration to change the dependencies or create another run configuration with different dependencies.

Comment: Javadoc: [_"Clients may subclass and instantiate this class."_](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/api/org/eclipse/pde/launching/EclipseApplicationLaunchConfiguration.html).

Comment: @howlger I said 'easily' - writing a new launch configuration is hard work.

Comment: Is it possible to create a subclass, customize it by overridding some methods and add it via extension point as a new launch configuration? Is there anything special to take care of here?

Comment: @howlger It is a long time since I last looked at this but I think it should be possible. However changing dependencies would require a lot of research to find out how that works.

Comment: I had two ways to modify launch configuration. One is to add a custom context menu to run by implementing "org.eclipse.pde.ui.launcher.EclipseLaunchShortcut" and overriding createLaunchConfiguration() seems to work. EclipsePluginValidationOperation and DependencyManager classes has to be accessed to determine the dependencies (Discouraged Access). But this seems to create the launch configuration expected but does not run the plugin. One the other way as greg mentioned we have to add an extension point "org.eclipse.debug.core.launchDelegates" and overriding the methods inside works.